# Clear all Content of the div except few elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose i have a div in which i have many elements like this

```
<div id="ans" style="background-color: #FFD993;
    color: #FFF;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px outset #4f6417;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;width:100%;text-align: center;height:33%;margin-bottom:    0px;">
    <input type="button" id="again" value="See Again"></input>
    <input type="button" id="prac" value="Practice"></input>
    <img id="theImg" src="result/' + rand + '.png" width="40%" height="60%"/>
    <a href="1.html">1</a>
    <a href="2.html">2</a>
    <p>This is Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I want to remove all the elements inside this `div` except these two buttons. I have used

```
$('#ans').empty();
```

but it will clear all the contents inside it. how can i filter it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about removing all the children except the inputs ?

```
$('#ans').children(':not(input[type="button"])').remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LZhrE/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**:

```
$('#ans').replaceWith(function() { return $('input', this) });
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvha/1/)**

---

If you want to keep the parent div as well, then you can do like @adeneo suggestion:

```
$('#ans').find(':not(input)').remove();
```

Comment: it is removing the style given to the div